# C# UserControl, Add Event Handler Manually

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am trying to add a new Mouse-click event handler manually to my web browser control, since web browser do not have mouse click event in its designer properties.

I need to run a code whenever user clicks inside the web browser control. This workaround adds in the handler that web browser does not have through its existing DocumentCompleted event handler.

When I run the code below, it returns a null exception. I am wondering if it is possible to be done this way.

EDIT: I have added while loop to ensure the webbrowser1 completes loading. However, now it gets stuck in the while loop. Does it mean that the webpage loading is never complete?

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Body_MouseDown);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void Body_MouseDown(Object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    if( e.MouseButtonsPressed == MouseButtons.Left)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("File in web browser selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: This might happen if your `Document` or `Body` in the page you are hosting is not loaded completely. Have you tried adding a condition check for `webBrowser1` `ReadyState` to be `WebBrowserReadyState.Complete` before you add handler?

Comment: After adding I realise the `webBrowser1`  is not in`WebBrowserReadyState.Complete` and the event handler I need is not added. How do I ensure it to be in `WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`?

Comment: `while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }` I tried this, but the code gets stuck in while loop.

Comment: Not a `while` loop but an `if` condition. Document complete handler will be hit for every state change of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Body_MouseDown);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Praty, I tried his but the event is never added as the webbrowser is never in ready state.

Comment: This is uncommon! What I would suggest is debug and see at which state you have `Document` and `Body` as not null and change the condition accordingly.